# What are those brackets for?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

We sang this song at Church and I am just wondering what these two symbols do.
[image: Second half of "On Jordan's Bank"]

Comment: What is the song?

Comment: @Aaron On Jordan's Bank

Comment: Please consider accepting Neal's answer, which is the better; I plan to delete mine, since updating it would only duplicate his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is from a hymn, the most likely explanation is that they are *accompanist introduction brackets*:

[image]

[Source](https://hymnary.org/page/fetch/TH1990/ix/high)

In this example from “A Mighty Fortress is Our God,” the accompanist would introduce the tune by playing only the bracketed sections.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---